# In Maoz Tsur should it say תִכּוֹן בֵּית זביחתי instead of תִכּוֹן בֵּית תְּפִלָּתִי

Tags: chanuka, korban, song-poetry

The word  תְּפִלָּתִי in the poem Maoz Tsur seems out of context:

תִכּוֹן בֵּית **תְּפִלָּתִי** וְשָׁם תּוֹדָה **נְזַבֵּחַ**

לְעֵת תָּכִין מַטְבֵּחַ מִצָּר הַמְנַבֵּחַ

אָז אֶגְמוֹר בְּשִׁיר מִזְמוֹר חֲנֻכַּת **הַמִּזְבֵּחַ**:

There are two references to korbonos נְזַבֵּחַ and הַמִּזְבֵּחַ so the word זביחתי would seem more appropriate than  תְּפִלָּתִי.

Comment: I'm no expert - but I'd assume that semi-repeating the same word in one line is rather unpoetic!

Comment: והביאותים אל הר קדשי ושמחתים בבית תפלתי...

Comment: הבית שעליו אני מתפלל, שאליו אני מייחל

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer may be from [here](http://www.zeevgalili.com/2013/11/18727):

> "תיכון בית תפילתי" – תבנה את בית המקדש העתידי. (השלישי) שנקרא גם 'בית תפילה'.
> "אז אגמור בשיר מזמור" – בעת הגאולה אשלים את תפילת ההלל עם חנוכת המזבח."

It seems that Tefillah is an inherent part of Beit Hamikdash. If the Mikdash was simply a house of sacrifice, ending the giving of thanks with a Shir Mizmor of Tefillah would be out of place. The only way would be to sacrifice. Therefore, the composer is telling us the important role Tefillah has in the Mikdash.

Another answer may be simply that "בית זביחתי" isn't a name for the Mikdash.

Answer (score 2):

possible answer to the question...

HKB”H promised that the bais hamikdosh will be the place where all humans will come to pray
and he will listen to them
even if they don’t bring or are non participants in 
the sacrifices 
that’s why it will be called “house of prayer”

שלמה המלך ביקש.....כשחינך הביהמ״קדש
נא רבש״ע !!!!שמע אל תפילות הבאים להתפלל
פה בבית מקדשך אפילו נכרי
וכתיב והביאותים אל הר.......כי ביתי בית תפילה 
יקרא לכל העמים

ק״בה הסכים שכל תפלה יתקבל אפילו נכרי 
אף שאינן שייכין בזביחות

ולכן נקרא ״בית תפלה״
שזה כבוד הבית שכל בריה יודע כי רק שם
יש להתפלל (אין עוד)

also.....
gamara in brachos 32 says..
that Tfillah is greater by kb”h
than korbonoss and even if not listening to korbonos he still listens to Tfillos